# PhpMyAdmin copy database function giving mysqli_query(): Empty query Warning

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Trying to copy a database in PhpMyAdmin via "Operations > Copy database to".

Settings: copy structure and data and CREATE DATABASE before copying unchecked as the database to copy to already exists.

PhpMyAdmin version: 4.8.2 & DirectAdmin 1.53.4 & MariaDB 10.0.33

Getting error:

```
Warning in ./libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php#213
 mysqli_query(): Empty query

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php#213: mysqli_query(
,
string '',
integer 0,
)
./libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php#319: PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->realQuery(
boolean false,
,
integer 0,
)
./libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php#169: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
boolean false,
integer 256,
integer 0,
boolean true,
)
./libraries/classes/Operations.php#373: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->query(boolean false)
./db_operations.php#83: PhpMyAdmin\Operations->runProcedureAndFunctionDefinitions(string 'rentals_xxxxxxxx')
```

Comment: This is either a bug in phpmyadmin or php. It might be worth raising a bug on phpmyadmin's github page.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks! Updating to the most recent version of PhpMyAdmin, PHP7.2, MariaDB and DA didn't help. So i'll raise the bug report. Thanks!

Comment: Issue submitted: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/issues/81